# Getting instance of object?

Tags: java, object

I have a slight problem. I wrote a function that should generate table for a list of objects (it could be Date or custom one or whichever). Parametars of this function are "List list" and "List headings". So, here is the question, why is this line

```
if (value.getClass().isInstance(Date.class) ...
```

not executing, even thou when I print value.getClass() is says the: class java.util.Date. Also a question, how to check if "value" is List? Thanks a lot in advance :)

Here is the part of the code:

```
for (Object o : list) {

    List<String> atributes = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (java.lang.reflect.Field field :o.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) { 
        field.setAccessible(true);
        Object value = field.get(o);
        if (value != null) {
            if (value.getClass().isInstance(Date.class)) {
                atributes.add(convertDateToString((java.util.Date) value));
            }
            atributes.add(value.toString());
        }
        } ...
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say that the line is not executing? Do you mean that it is always returning false?

Comment: Yeah, sorry for bad expression :)

Comment: Because `Date.class` is not an instance of `Date`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're misusing [`Class#isInstance`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInstance-java.lang.Object-), which returns true if `Date.class` is an instance of `value.getClass()`:

> Determines if the specified Object is assignment-compatible with the object represented by this Class. This method is the dynamic equivalent of the Java language `instanceof` operator. The method returns true if the specified Object argument is non-null and can be cast to the reference type represented by this Class object without raising a ClassCastException. It returns false otherwise.

Rather, you want either:

```
if(value instanceof Date)
```

or

```
if(Date.class.isInstance(value))
```

Comment: @HansJohanbach No problem, feel free to mark the check mark if you believe this answer helped you completely.

Answer (score 3):

The correct way to check if an object is an instance of some Class is to use "instanceof" statement.

So, you should be doing this:

```
if (value instanceof Date) {
     atributes.add(convertDateToString((java.util.Date) value));
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

`value.getClass().isInstance(Date.class)` asks if `Date.class` which is of type `Class` is an instance of a class that is assign-compatible with the class of `value`. That is `false` unless `value` is an instance of `Class` or `Object`.

Use operator `instanceof` instead:

```
if (value instanceof Date) …
```